# How to generate a report of all changes in AD account profiles

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

How can I generate a list (spreadsheet, perhaps) of all user accounts in AD that have been updated since a particular date?

I am thinking to do this in C#, but any .net method would be acceptable.

Here is the context: I use a component in my sharepoint portal that allows users to update their AD profiles themselves.  However, I need to also update my mailing lists, therefore I need to know when they update their email address.  Thus, I need to fetch the changes.

Answer (score 1):

AD is slow when it comes to advanced querying. I guess it could be cheaper to extract a complete list of users from AD and then search for changes in your mailing lists assuming you have them in a database. The complete list of user names together with their emails should generate rather quickly (depending on the number of users of course).

Edit: a simple helper Powershell script to quickly fetch users from the AD

```
# Get the RootDSE
$rootDSE=[ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE"

# Get the defaultNamingContext
$Ldap="LDAP://"+$rootDSE.defaultNamingContext

# Create the output file
$outFile=".\users\userList_{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.csv" -f (Get-Date)

# Get all users 
$filter="(&(ObjectClass=user))"

# create the Header for the Output File
$header="name;userPrincipalName;mail"
$timeStamp=

# Check if the file exists and if it does with the same timestamp remove it
if(Test-Path $outFile)
{
  Remove-Item $outFile
}

# create the output file and write the header
Out-File -InputObject $header -FilePath $outFile

# main routine
function GetUserListToFile()
{
  # create a adsisearcher with the filter
  $searcher=[adsisearcher]$Filter

  # setup the searcher properties
  $Ldap = $Ldap.replace("LDAP://","")
  $searcher.SearchRoot="LDAP://$Ldap"
  $searcher.propertiesToLoad.Add("name")
  $searcher.propertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName")
  $searcher.propertiesToLoad.Add("mail")

  $searcher.pageSize=1000

  # find all objects matching the filter
  $results=$searcher.FindAll()

  # create an empty array
  $ADObjects = @()
  foreach($result in $results)
  {
    # work through the array and build a custom PS Object
    [Array]$propertiesList = $result.Properties.PropertyNames
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    foreach(property in $propertiesList)
    { 
       $obj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name $property -value ([string]$result.Properties.Item($property))
    }
    # add the object to the array
    $ADObjects += $obj

    # build the output line
    $lineOut=$obj.Name+";"+ $obj.UserPrincipalName+";"+ $obj.mail

    # Write the line to the output file
    Out-File -Append -InputObject $lineOut -FilePath $outFile
  }

  Return $ADObjects
}

# main routine
GetUserListToFile
```

Comment: Do you think the querying would be that adverse if there are less than 1000 profiles?

Comment: Does it matter? You can update everything without checking if it is modified or not. 1000 is not much, when we query 50k+ AD it really takes time (few minutes).

Comment: I didn't mean updating the AD but your mailing lists.

Comment: Okay, when you say, "query AD directly", do you mean using C# to fetch the data?  I suppose I can just compare the list I get from AD to the list I get from my mail server.  Then, as you say, I don't need the update times.  Just the values.

Comment: I don't think that would do it.  That script would fetch all users, and there is no way to know if anything in AD is changed (hence my question).  I can't do a comparison to my list because the list may also have changed.  But if I can fetch all the changed user profiles since a particular date, then I can perhaps synchronize against the changes made to my mailing list.